# not unless vs. generally not unless

Tags: grammar

thank you for your attention.

My question is about the difference in meaning between the following sentences:

(i) "A novel is not considered unless it successfully engages the imagination of most readers"

(ii) "A novel is generally not considered unless it successfully engages the imagination of most readers"

For me, (i) means a novel is considered only when it successfully engages the imagination of most readers.

However, I am not sure whether (ii) means the same or not? Could I interpret the (ii) as "A novel is generally considered only when it successfully engages the imagination of most readers".

Thank you very much for your time.
Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is categorical, the second general.

Thus, SOME novels could be considered (for publication purposes, perhaps) even if they fail to successfully engage the imagination of most readers in 2), but 1) says that ONLY those novels that successfully engage the imagination of most readers are considered.